# Why isn't my DataGridViewComboBoxColumn data-bound when I add it to the DataGridView?

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, datagridview

I'm trying to add a bound `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn` to a bound `DataGridView`. My combobox column works in that the dropdown is filled out. However, changing the selected value doesn't update my data-source.

Here's the relevant code:

```
var SplitsView = new BindingList<SplitPaymentView>(
    Splits.Select(t => new SplitPaymentView(t)).ToList());

dgvSplits.DataSource = SplitsView;

var mediaCol = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn() {
   Name = "Media",
   DataSource = AvailableMedias,
   DisplayIndex = 4,
   DisplayMember = "Description",
   ValueMember = "ID",
   ValueType = typeof(short),
   HeaderText = "Payment Media",
};

mediaCol.DataPropertyName = "MediaId";

dgvSplits.Columns.Add(mediaCol);
```

My `SplitPaymentView` class does have a property `public short MediaId {get;set;}`. However, when I set a breakpoint in the setter, it's not called when I change the value of the combobox.

Then I checked the value of the new column's `IsDataBound` property, and it's always `false`.

The other (autogenerated) columns in the dgv are bound properly. I thought I just had to set the column's `DataPropertyName` and add it to the dgv, but it seems I'm missing something.

What am I missing?

Comment: Does it bind when you tab out of the cell? I think the binding occurs on end edit in the cell.

Comment: I've tried your code in a little sample app, and it only calls into the backing type when you end edit on the cell, in my case I just clicked another cell. The properties you have set are correct, assuming that your string property names are all correct.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work for me, even if I move to a new row. Can you check if your column's `IsDataBound` property gets set to `true` after you add the column to the dgv?

Comment: Yes it is set to true, presumably by the grid as I don't set it myself. One different is I bind the grid to a Binding Source, which is bound to a BindingList<T>.

Comment: Hmm, tried that just in case.. didn't help though. I must have something subtly wrong.. Thanks for going to the effort of checking it!